# Connecting flare fitting together

Tags: gas

I am looking to replace my cooktop.  My current gas valve is a one-piece valve, with one end connected to the gas pipe, and the other with a 3/8 flare fitting, which is connected to a 3/8 flexible gas line.  The new cooktop though requires a 1/2-in flexible gas line.  Is there a way to connect a 1/2-in flexible gas connector to a 3/8 flare fitting?

Thanks

Comment: pics of the end you want to connect would help.  Otherwise the only answer is you need an adapter 3/8 to 1/2.  Your could also take the pics to a hardware store and ask the clerk to help find the correct adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adapters are available from 3/8 inch female flare to 1/2 inch flare or pipe thread. But what's the input side of that valve -- 1/2 inch pipe thread, by chance? In that case I think you'll do better to simply replace the valve. Pick one with 1/2 inch FIP on both sides.